# Finding place of birth for Martha Hyde Bell of Quebec?

Tags: birth-records, canada, 1820s, quebec

What I know:

- Martha Hyde was born 1822?
- Died February 1849 in Quebec.
- Martha Hyde married William Bell in 1847 at Saint Paul’s Presbyterian Church in Quebec.
- Martha gave birth to my great grandmother, Mary Ann Bell, in May 1848 in Quebec.
- Martha Hyde Bell is buried in Barber Cemetery in Quebec.
- I know that William Bell was Irish.
- William took Mary Ann as a baby to the state of Maryland USA.

**Where was Martha born?**

Comment: To avoid us repeating your effort so far, can you tell us your sources for what you know? Many thanks and welcome.

Comment: When you say "Quebec," do you mean Quebec City, or somewhere in the province of Quebec?

Comment: I ask because there doesn't seem to have been a St Paul's Presbyterian Church in Quebec City- (https://genealogyensemble.files.wordpress.com/2015/07/presbyterian-churches-of-quebec-city-and-montreal.pdf)

Comment: I would strongly consider looking for immigration records from Ireland. The time frame fits a major [Irish migration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irish_Canadians#Irish_in_Quebec), and I actually have a Martha Hyde of my own, whose father was born in Ireland, so Hyde *can* definitely be Irish.